# T-test formula when population standard deviation is known

Tags: self-study, t-test, sample-size

I got this question from my mentor.

Marks obtained by 10 MBA students in Statistics paper (out of 50) is given below.
20.5, 18.25, 10.23, 15.47, 35.62, 47.64, 12.30, 29.65, 38.5, 14.79.
Test whether the mean score of all students is 20. Where standard deviation is given as 10.

Here we cannot use z-test since n<30 and we know σ. So what should t-test's denominator be? s/√n or simply σ

Please feel free to edit the question

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag wki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question according to the guidelines there.

Comment: If the data are not normal, you won't have a t-distribution in any case. If the data can be assumed normal or nearly normal (so you'd have a t-distribution if you used the sample sd), then you will have a z-test. (In any case, the idea of having a cut-off at n=30 is nonsensical; there's no good basis for that. Sometimes n=5 is plenty. Sometimes n=200 isn't enough)

Comment: The formula for the Student t statistic is quoted in hundreds of posts--but they are hard to find by searching.  In closing this as a duplicate, I have pointed to one of many questions which give the correct formula.